# Admob : Animated GIFs are not supported. Please upload a different image

Tags: admob, ads, animated-gif

I was trying to upload a animated .gif House ads in Admob I am getting a message "Animated GIFs are not supported. Please upload a different image". I can see many animated ads displayed in my android device how is that possible, is there anything i am missing?

Answer (score 0):

They may not be Admob ads. They could come from another ad network (perhaps via mediation).

Answer (score 0):

I just uploaded a sample gif on Admob with 2 colors alternating and got no issues. I did not continue the ad campaign though, so I don't know if the animated GIF is evaluated later on, but as of now, it uploaded correctly and the preview displayed correctly. When did your error message happen?

Edit: wait... are you using "House Ads Campaign"? I didn't try that out, but maybe the House Ads do not allow animations. Just guessing though. In the sample case above I only tried the paid ad campaign.